# Bash syntax with curl seems wrong

Tags: bash, shell, curl, command

I try to figure out why the command below doesn't work because on one UDM-Pro it worked perfectly.

```
dl_url=$(curl -fsL "https://api.github.com/repos/boostchicken-dev/udm-utilities/releases/latest" | awk '$0 ~ /"browser_download_url"/ {sub(/.*:\s*"/,"",$0); gsub("\"", "", $0); print $2}')
```

```
curl -Lo udm-boot_latest.deb $dl_url
```

The output is the following:

[Output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dwuB.png)

> unifi-os shell
>
> root@ubnt:/# dl_url=$(curl -fsL "https://api.github.com/repos/boostchicken-dev/udm-utilities/releases/latest" | awk '$0 ~ /"browser_download_url"/ {sub(/.*:\s*"/,"",$0); gsub(""", "", $0); print $2}')
>
> root@ubnt:/# curl -Lo udm-boot_latest.deb $dl_url
>
> curl: no URL specified! curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
>
> root@ubnt:/#

What is wrong with this command? On another UDM-Pro it worked perfectly.

Thx a lot! :)

I don't know what I can change?

Comment: Do it in pieces to see where the process breaks down: `curl ... > tmpfile` then `awk ... < tmpfile`

Comment: The `\s` in the awk regex looks suspicious: not every awk supports that

Comment: Note also that curl will output headers with `\r\n` line endings: you may need to remove the carriage return`

Comment: Separately, [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Putting the `set -x` command at the beginning to get an execution trace is another good way to get info about what's happening (especially, what the `dl_url` variable is actually getting set to).

Comment: Thx a lot to all, I'll try it! 
It's also much easier when I follow the api link and copy the url under "browser_download_url" manually. Like: curl -Lo udm-boot_latest.deb "Manually copied link". But again I'll try to modify the command above. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you likely did not use the command in an **identical** fashion to the previous successful cases.

The triple double-quote is where the big problem lies.  Logically, you **cannot** encapsulate any type of quotation (*single or double*) by the same type of quotation, so that >> **"""** << is a bust!  You need to use the form **/"/** instead, which is hinted at by the documentation for the AWK gsub function specifying **regexp** in the first field.

Also, there is no need for the use of sub in this script.  You can avoid that by making the reference to **$2**.  The resulting assignment should look like this:

```
PROJ_DEPOT="https://api.github.com/repos/boostchicken-dev/udm-utilities/releases/latest"
dl_url=$(curl -fsL "${PROJ_DEPOT}" | 
    awk '$0 ~ /"browser_download_url"/ { gsub(/"/, "", $0 ) ; print $2 }' )
```